# Display diacritical marks without the dotted ring

Tags: unicode, fonts, diacritics

Is there any way to display diacritical marks like following without the dotted ring?

1. ◌́
2. ◌̀
3. ◌̃

Answer (score 1):

Each of these items are actually two characters in Unicode that are combined via ligatures or mark-to-base features in the font. The dotted circle is 0x25CC, and the marks you have here are 0x301, 0x300, and 0x303 - each of these are [designed to combine with the previous character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character), but there are [non-combining versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacing_Modifier_Letters) of each of these: 0x2CA, 0x2CB, and 0x2DC.

So you can delete the dotted circle from the beginning of the character (it may be difficult to figure out where this character is, since the marks have a width of zero), and replace it with a space, but it may display in odd ways depending on what's surrounding it:

1. ́
2. ̀
3. ̃

Or use the non-combining versions of these marks:

1. ˊ
2. ˋ
3. ˜

Comment: Could you please explain more about these?